# RecyclerView childs, how to connect 2 or more views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello I have a `RecyclerView`, and I use `HorizontalScrollView in children of the`RecyclerView`. I need to scroll all of them when I scrolling one. Anyone can tell me How to make that,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're doing something similar to what I did where you have some sort of tabular view and the `HorizontalScrollView`s are all the same width.

This is how I did it:

First I made a customization to the `HorizontalScrollView` so I could get event notifications when the view was swiped:

```
public class HorizontalScrollView extends android.widget.HorizontalScrollView {

    private OnScrollListener mListener;

    public HorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onScrollChanged(this, l);
        }
    }

    public interface OnScrollListener {
        public void onScrollChanged(View view, int scrollX);
    }
}
```

Then when I create the `ViewHolder`s I add a listener that will set all the views to the same scrollX:

```
    view.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(View scrollView, int scrollX) {

            for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof HorizontalScrollView && child != scrollView) {
                    HorizontalScrollView scrollView2 = (HorizontalScrollView) child;
                    if (scrollView2.getScrollX() != scrollX) {
                        scrollView2.setScrollX(scrollX);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is just for illustration purposes; don't expect to copy/paste this and have it work.

I'm assuming that your `ViewHolder` can get a reference to your `RecyclerView` to access all the current list items.

This code had some problems, when you swiped one view then swiped another view while everything was still moving from the first swipe, things could get out of sync.  But this is a basic idea to get you started in a positive direction.

Comment: I can't understand for what view you set OnScrollListener

Comment: `view` in this case is the special `HorizontalScrollView` class listed before.  That's the view that is created for your `ViewHolder`. When you are setting up your `ViewHolder` you set the listener on that view.  If I called it `itemView` like it was in the `ViewHolder` constructor maybe that would have made more sense.